# Integrate facebook fan page with phone application

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-page, fan-page

I have a windows phone 7 application and I want it to integrate it with Facebook. I have a facebook "fan page" but do not currently have a facebook "app" for my phone application. Is it possible to integrate "Like" functionality for a facebook "fan page" the way we can integrate a facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible to "Like" something via a web link.
You'll either have to redirect the user to a page (via WebBrowserTask) with the option there or embed a WebBrowser control which points to a page hosting the like functionality.

Comment: I guess i was somewhere wrong when I said "Like" functionality. I actually want to "write" on user's wall using "fan page". I know it is possible with facebook "App".. but not sure if the "fan page" can do the same.